# R - streamR package - using filterStream to capture all tweets?

Tags: r, twitter

I need to capture all the tweets from a very small rural community (that does not generate many tweets overall) in a given period of time. Providing keywords might very well filter out most of the few tweets.

Is there a way to use `filterStream()` to capture all tweets from a geocoded area, regardless of the tweets content ? In other words, is it possible to use `filterStream` without providing a specific string or string vector containing keywords to track ? I couldn't find anything about generic queries in the help files or the twitter API doc.
 Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can leave the "track" argument empty and just add the coordinates that define the geographic box around the area you are interested in with the "locations" argument.

For example:

```
filterStream("tweetsUS.json", locations = c(-125, 25, -66, 50), 
   timeout = 300, oauth = my_oauth)
```

captures tweets sent from the US. To know more about how this works, you can check the documentation for this parameter [here](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/request-parameters#locations).

Comment: thank you. So filterStream() behaves in a different manner than searchTwitter() (from TwitteR package) that always requires a search string vector.